# jQuery obtain value of selected dropdown item based on class

Tags: jquery

I have tried the following code to obtain the `value` of a selected dropdown based on its class but it returns `undefined` - could anybody suggest where I am going wrong please - si it connected with the fact I have multiple dropdowns?

**Situation**

> I have three dropdown boxes all using the same `class` - `class='hotel'`.

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option class="hotel" name="ABC" value="df435">Birmingham </option>
</select>

<select>    
    <option class="hotel" name="ACME" value="cvf53">Leeds</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option class="hotel" name="XYZ" value="re4">London</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
var hotel = $(".hotel option:selected").val();
```

Comment: You've said you have dropboxes using the same class. How many `<select>`s are there and where is the class set? Have you put the class on the options?? **Please show your HTML**

Comment: Ok you did put the class on the option, not the select. Odd that you only have one option in each select.

Comment: Why class on option? ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can get it like this:

### HTML:

```
<select class="hotel">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Some Option</option>
</select>
```

### JQUERY:

```
$(".hotel").val();
```

### FIDDLE:

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FDHeF/)

**UPDATE:**

For multiple dropdown with same class you can do this:

### HTML:

```
<select class="hotel">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Some Option</option>
</select>

<select class="hotel">
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Some Option</option>
</select>

<select class="hotel">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Some Option</option>
</select>
```

### JQUERY:

```
$(".hotel").each(function () {

    alert($(this).val());

})
```

Then use change event:

```
$(".hotel").on("change",function(){

alert($(this).val())

})
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply - also returns `undefined`.

Comment: are you sure you have option value present like: ``<option value="somevalue">SomeText</option>``

Comment: What happens if there are three dropdowns?   I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: you have to iterate then if you are getting them not in change event

Comment: then you have to do like this:``$(".hotel").each(function(){

alert($(this).val());
    
})``

Comment: This brings back all values for all dropdowns - I only want the `one` that is selected.

Comment: Then in its change event use`` $(this) .val()``to get current one value