# Why does select class return undefined value?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out why my select list option values return undefined when I get them by class, but if the list is accessed by id it works fine?

I have tried accessing the select option values by class, this doesn't work.

### javascript

#### This script returns undefined for the var listTopic

```
var schoolSelect = $(".schoolSelect"),
stage2 = $("#stage2Div"),
stage3 = $("#stage3Div");

  getSelectValue = function() {
    var selectedValue = schoolSelect.val();
    var listTopic = String(selectedValue);
    console.log('This is the list topic' + ' ' + listTopic);
    if (listTopic == "Topic_MI_School_of_Phil") {
      console.log("hurray!")
    }
    else {
      console.log("boo!")
    }
    return listTopic;        
  };

  // Stage 2 Click Event
  stage2.click(function() {
    if (getSelectValue().length == 0) {
      popup.addClass("show");
    } else if (getSelectValue().length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < getSelectValue().length; i++) {
        var message = createSLMessage("/topics/" + getSelectValue());
        sendMessage(message);
      }
    }
    // selectedOption()
  });
  //Stage 3 Click Event
  stage3.click(function() {
    if (getSelectValue().length == 0) {
      popup.addClass("show");
    } else if (getSelectValue().length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < getSelectValue().length; i++) {
        var message = createFLMessage("/topics/" + getSelectValue());
        sendMessage(message);
      }
    }
    // selectedOption()
  });
```

#### html

```
<div class="lockdownPopup" id="clearLockdownPopup">
        <div class="lockdownPopupInner">
        <div class="lockdownPopupClose" id="clearLockdownClose">X</div>
        <select class="schoolSelect" size="2">
            <option value="Topic_MI_School_of_Phil">St Mary's High</option>
        </select></div>
        <div class="alertButton" id="clearAlertDiv">Clear Lockdown Alerts</div>

      </div>
      <div class="lockdownPopup" id="softLockdownPopup">
          <div class="lockdownPopupInner">
        <div class="lockdownPopupClose" id="softLockdownClose">X</div>
        <select class="schoolSelect" size="2">
          <option value="Topic_MI_School_of_Phil">St Mary's High</option>
        </select>
        <div class="alertButton" id="stage2Div">Initiate Soft Lockdown</div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="lockdownPopup" id="fullLockdownPopup">
          <div class="lockdownPopupInner">
        <div class="lockdownPopupClose" id="fullLockdownClose">X</div>
        <select class="schoolSelect" size="2">
            <option value="Topic_MI_School_of_Phil">St Mary's High</option>
        </select>
        <div class="alertButton" id="stage3Div">Initiate Full Lockdown</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

#### This returns the correct value - The only difference is that it is accessed by id, obviously I can only access one list at a time this way so I would have to triple my code, which I would rather avoid

```
var schoolSelect = $("#schoolSelect"),
stage2 = $("#stage2Div"),
stage3 = $("#stage3Div");

  getSelectValue = function() {
    var selectedValue = schoolSelect.val();
    var listTopic = String(selectedValue);
    console.log('This is the list topic' + ' ' + listTopic);
    if (listTopic == "Topic_MI_School_of_Phil") {
      console.log("hurray!")
    }
    else {
      console.log("boo!")
    }
    return listTopic;        
  };

  // Stage 2 Click Event
  stage2.click(function() {
    if (getSelectValue().length == 0) {
      popup.addClass("show");
    } else if (getSelectValue().length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < getSelectValue().length; i++) {
        var message = createSLMessage("/topics/" + getSelectValue());
        sendMessage(message);
      }
    }
    // selectedOption()
  });
  //Stage 3 Click Event
  stage3.click(function() {
    if (getSelectValue().length == 0) {
      popup.addClass("show");
    } else if (getSelectValue().length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < getSelectValue().length; i++) {
        var message = createFLMessage("/topics/" + getSelectValue());
        sendMessage(message);
      }
    }
    // selectedOption()
  });
```

I would like the correct value to be returned. If I add an id to any one of the select lists, I can then access that id the correct value is returned.

Comment: Oh sorry that's supposed to just be var selectedValue = schoolSelect.val(); I had changed it to see if trying to find the value may work. It doesn't work with either syntax as long as I am trying to get the value of a class rather than an id. I've updated the code.

Comment: I've also tried loading each popup in it's own html file so that there is only one id in the DOM at a time, but that provides a whole host of async issues.

Comment: Can you include the html in your first snippet that is not working with class?  Also is this logic in a document ready, or where is the javascript on the page in relation to your html?

Comment: Also when you edit your question you can click the `<>` button, or press Ctrl+M to bring up the onsite editor to make a runnable snippet of your issue.

Comment: The class selector returns 3 items where one is expected since it needs to know which select box you meant.. Instead of getSelected function may be use “this” keyword  from stage.click function to refer to its nested select box..

Comment: This is a lot of code, you should always try to come up with simplifications of your problem and remove unnecessary noise. As much as I'd like to help, I'm not willing to read through that much code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JuanMendes I don't really feel like this is that much code and each bit of it is required to reproduce the issue I am experiencing...If I removed any of it the context would be lost. The only reason I have two blocks of js is to show that when I use id it works, as expected.

Comment: @Taplar oddly enough, in the code snippet generator I was able to access the ids, until I ran the tidy function in the snippet generator. Then it went back to undefined. I'll try again to make a snippet.

Comment: @bestinamir I have tried different iterations of $(this) and I can't seem to get that to work either. As I mentioned to Taplar , in the code snippet generator I was able to get the values but I have no idea why...

Comment: @ptrugby4141 I guarantee you you can remove more than half the code, then you could actually have a runnable example. You can at least get rid of `createSLMessage` and `sendMessage` And you should try to boil the problem just down the the query calls, without requiring clicks. Just trying to help, could be the reason you're not getting a lot of answers

Comment: If you google this you can find examples how to do it..

Comment: @JuanMendes I suppose I left those pieces in there because the createFLMessage references me attempting to collect the values and has the getSelectValue() function in it so I thought maybe I could have been doing something wrong there. I appreciate your input though, thank you for trying to help. I've used Stack Overflow for a long time to find answers but really just started asking questions recently as I go through the process of building this application so I'm learning the best protocols.

Comment: @bestinamir I did find this example on SO but I am having trouble applying it to my scenario. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726076/jquery-obtain-value-of-selected-dropdown-item-based-on-class

Comment: Still not using relative selection, just a loop.. Please try https://stackoverflow.com/a/27964162/10634638 or https://forum.jquery.com/topic/affecting-dropdown-menu-with-button-click

Comment: But i may be wrong..